# Conditional Future in Scala

Tags: scala

Given these two futures, I need to run the first one only if a condition is true (see `if y>2`). But I get an exception `Future.filter predicate is not satisfied`. What does this mean and how to fix the example?

```
object TestFutures extends App {

  val f1 = Future {
    1
  }

  val f2 = Future {
    2
  }

  val y = 1

  val x = for {
    x1 <- f1 if y>2
    x2 <- f2
  }  yield x1 + x2


  Thread.sleep(5000)
  println(x)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` is not really something you should be able to do on a `Future` - what would a `Future` that didn't pass the condition return? From your example: we still need to have a value for `x1` (even if it fails the `if`) to use in the `yield x1 + x2`.

Therefore, the `filter` method on `Future` is designed to fail hard when the predicate evaluates to false. It is an "assert" of sorts. You probably would prefer something like this (that provides a default value for `x1` if the condition fails):

```
val x = for {
  x1 <- if (y > 2) f1 else Future.successful(/* some-default-value-for-x1 */)
  x2 <- f2
}  yield x1 + x2
```

Comment: @ps0604 I disagree. `filter` is well-defined on `Future`. A future means "you may have an answer", and if we filter that, we could say: "you may have an answer if the condition is true". The `Failure` state is what we would expected if the condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: ** the comment above should read "you may *eventually* have an answer" otherwise that would be an `Option`

Comment: To the down voter, care to explain what you disagree with?

Comment: I did leave an explanation why I disagree with the answer. More specifically:  "filter is not really something you should be able to do on a Future" is a false assertion and misleading for future readers, specially when the answer is marked as "accepted".

Comment: moreover, this is not answering the requirement " I need to run the first one only if a condition is true" but providing a side-track instead (fallback values). So if `f1` was "Future(Delete all the database)" and the condition was "If user said yes three times", this is saying `Future.successful("it's all fine")` while the db was deleted anyway.

Comment: @maasg Yep. Just realized your later point. I agree your answer is correct and mine not so. Just tried to delete mine, but I cannot as it is accepted. Hopefully the OP will switch to accept yours. Upvoted yours in the meantime.

Comment: Really helpful answer--thank you!  I was using `else Future.successful {}` which was causing the same error message in some cases but not others. It only seems to be allowed in cases where there is a default value for `x1`'s type.  To fix I changed to using an `Option` so that I could `else Future.successful(None)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The question contains some terminology issues.

Given the requirement, *"I need to run the first (future) one only if a condition is true"*, then one possible implementation of the requirement would be:

```
val f1 = if (cond) Some(Future(op)) else None
```

This is because a `Future` will start its execution once it's defined.

Going back to the expression in the question:

```
val x = for {
  x1 <- f1 if y>2
  x2 <- f2
}  yield x1 + x2
```

This is saying "I want the ***result*** of `f1` `if(cond)`" and not "I want to ***execute*** `f1` `if(cond)`".

This would be a way: (note how the futures are defined within the for-comprehension, and the condition is outside):

```
val x = if (y > 2) {
  for {
      x1 <- Future(op1)
      x2 <- Future(op2)
  }  yield x1 + x2
} else ???
```

The proper use of guards in for-comprehensions is to evaluate an expression against values coming from the computation expressed by the for-comprehension. For example:

"I want to *execute* `f2` only if the result of `f1` is greater than `y`"

```
val x = for {
  x1 <- f1
  x2 <- Future(op) if x1 > y
}  yield x1 + x2
```

Note how the condition here involves an intermediate result of the computation (`x1` in this case)

---

One side note: to wait for the result of a future, use `Await.result(fut, duration)` instead of `Thread.sleep(duration)`