# Running futures sequentially

Tags: scala

The objective of the code below is to execute Future `f3` or `f4` depending on a condition. Note that the condition depends on the result of Future `f1` or `f2`, so it has to wait. This seems to work, however since `f1` and `f2` are futures this code shouldn't run sequentially. Is this code correct?

```
object TestFutures extends App {

  val f1 = Future { 1 }
  val f2 = Future { 2 }
  val f3 = Future { 3 }
  val f4 = Future { 4 }

  val y = 1

  for {
    condition <- if (y>0) f1 else f2
    _ <- if (condition==1) f3.map {a => println("333")} else f4.map {b => println("444")}
  }  yield ()


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Comment: "Is this code correct?" -- it's not clear what's correct in this situation. I think that the code matches your description, so the answer seems to be "yes".

Comment: what about the answer that says that all the future functions already run before the for comprehension?

Comment: It is true, you can check :p

Comment: I wonder whether the answer to your previous question also answers this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40778487/conditional-future-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not correct. When you create a `Future` like you do it, it starts the computations immediately. Before reaching `for` comprehension, all of your 4 futures are running already. You need to create them later, depending on the conditions.

```
val y = 1
for {
  condition <- if (y > 0) Future { 1 } else Future { 2 }
  _ <- if (condition == 1) 
    Future { 3 }.map(a => println("333"))
  else 
    Future { 4 }.map(b => println("444"))
} yield ()
```

It is probably good to extract creating each of those to a method, that you will just call, for sake of readability.

It should be obvious they start running when they are created because you can just say

```
Future(1).map(x => println(x))
```

and it works without any sort of triggering. Anyway try to run the following code

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def printWhenCompleted[A](f: Future[A]): Future[A] = f.map { x =>
    println(x)
    x
}

val f1 = printWhenCompleted(Future { 1 })
val f2 = printWhenCompleted(Future { 2 })
val f3 = printWhenCompleted(Future { 3 })

for {
  r3 <- f3
  r2 <- f2
  r1 <- f1
} yield r1 + r2 + r3
```

it should give you those numbers in random order, instead of sequential `3, 2, 1`

### Edit

Here is implementation of the first code (without `println`) using `flatMap`

```
val futureCondition = if (y > 0) Future(1) else Future(2)
futureCondition.flatMap(condition => if (condition == 1) Future(3) else Future(4))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to run Future  `f3` only if the result of `condition` is equals to `1`, therefore I need to wait for the result. What should be the approach?

Comment: I think I already implemented what you are asking for. So basically: first depending on `y` value, we are running `f1` or `f2`. Then we "await" on result using `condition <-`. Then if `condition == 1`, we run `f3` otherways `f4`. Initialization of future which triggers execution is delayed here because those arrows are actually translated to flatMap, so we just create a function, that will be called later and only then will create a future. I added `flatMap` example to the answer.